# Use package / package-lock for acknowledgments?

Tags: licensing, attribution, dependencies, package

I wanted to create a site with acknowledgments/attributions for all the packages used in my project (that's even required for the MIT licenses). So I thought about using `package.json` for that purpose. But as I saw `package-lock.json` I started doubting which licenses I have to credit?

- `Package` contains all directly used files
- `Package-lock` also contains the dependencies of these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, your project relies on functionality supplied by some package X. It doesn't matter if your code relies on it directly or if it relies on package Y which in turn relies on package X - the bottom line is that without package X, your project wouldn't work.

In short - you need to acknowledge all the packages you're using, whether directly or indirectly, so `pacakge-lock.json` may be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!